# why is my material not showing on the model?

Tags: mesh, uv

so I got to this point by making tons of blocks and putting them in a pattern... after I joined them all I created a material for it and added a texture... I opened that texture in the UV editor and went into edit mode on the model and unwrapped it.. I don't see any change in color when I look at the "texture" and "material" mode but when I change to "Texture Paint" I get the weird mix of green/black/grey etc...

HELP

here are pictures showing the problem:
[image]

Comment: I assume you'd like to see image from the left shown on the mesh on the right. Do you have any other slots in the *Toolshelf* > *Slots* panel > *Slots* rollout except for the image 'palate.png' ?

Comment: sry I don't know what that is >.< this maybe? [link](http://prntscr.com/c7cqgd)

Comment: ok so when I make the material shadeless I can see the weird mix when I change the display method to material

Comment: OK I seem to have fixed the problem by making a palate with 10x10 sections instead of 1x1 for each color....